# Página de código com acentuação no Prompt de Comando

Tags: firebird, cmd, console, acentuação

Ao ser atualizada a aplicação do meu sistema, uma linha de comando é chamada para executar um script para atualização do banco de dados. O script chama a ferramenta **Isql** do **Firebird** enviando como parâmetro o arquivo que contém as instruções SQL. O que acontece é que há palavras com acentuação nesse arquivo e como o Isql é uma Aplicação de Console, não está sendo enviado os acentos como deveria e o Isql está retornando um erro de string deformada.

A linha de comando chamada pela aplicação é a seguinte:

```
isql.exe "localhost:C:\Sistema\Banco\DADOS.FDB" -u SYSDBA -p masterkey -i SCRIPTSQL.txt
```

Segue um exemplo executando diretamente no **Prompt de Comando**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei com os "Códigos de Página (Code Page)" no Console: 1250, 1252, 860, etc. Mas ainda assim o erro permanece. O interessante é que ao realizar "selects" o resultado vem acentuado corretamente, mas neste caso para enviar a string acentuada é que está ocorrendo o erro. Existe algum outro "Page Code" para ser utilizado no Prompt de Comando para que a acentuação seja identificada corretamente?

Comment: Qual é a acentuação? `´`?

Comment: Qualquer palavra que tenha acentos: Código, Não, Açúcar, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Tente usar a página de código `65001`:

```
chcp 65001
```

Comment: não funcionou, esse código deve inserir junto algum caractere inválido, nem chega a dar "commit" no banco, a ferramenta Isql é finalizada imediatamente se a palavra utilizada possuir acentos.